# django queries: OR operator, should return only one record

Tags: mysql, django

In Django, MySQL setup the following query

> data = Recording.objects.get(Q(name='xyz') | Q(name="default"))

This throw `MultipleObjectsReturned` as both `xyz`and `default` records are present in the DB and MySQL returns both object on `OR operation` queries. (That's correct MySQL behavior)

Is there a way in Django/MySQL where the above query would return only one object even when both the records are present in DB?

**Note**: Constrain is only 1 query should be used to fetch the data and the query should return specific object (i.e xyz) first.only if it is not present shall the `default` object be returned

Comment: Which do you want to return when you find multiple?..

Comment: @sayse i want specific (ie xyz) object when its present, only when It is not present do i want the default object.

Answer (score 1):

`.get` should be used to retrieve a single record, as you noticed. Use `filter` otherwise:

```
data = Recording.objects.filter(Q(name='xyz') | Q(name="default")).first()
```

If which one matters, use `order_by` to arrange the order.

You could also use:

```
data = Recording.objects.filter(Q(name='xyz') | Q(name="default"))[0]
```

Which is practically the same. For more information see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first).

Comment: the [0] element could be anything 'xyz' or 'default' , What i want is if 'xyz' if present return it. otherwise give me  default obj..

Comment: As I said, use `order_by` to control which one comes first from the two.